# SimpleDateFormat.parse() return incorrect date for format "YYYY/MMM/d"

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I do not understand why after parsing I recieve other date:

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MMM/d");
String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(dateString);
date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

```
Tue Apr 09 12:18:35 AST 2019
2019/Apr/9
Mon Dec 31 12:00:00 AST 2018
```

Comment: I **strongly** advise you to [drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) the Date, Calendar and SimpleDateFormat classes and start using the [new Java Date and Time API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro) (in the pacakge `java.time`).

Comment: @MCEmperor thanks, will look into it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you correct the year format to be

> yyyy

instead of

> YYYY

things will work as expected

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/d");
```

[*Java 7 introduced YYYY as a new date pattern to identify the date week year.*](https://www.juandebravo.com/2015/04/10/java-yyyy-date-format/)

Answer (score 0):

can you please change the year as yyyy

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/d");
```

these are the patterns for simpleDateFormatter

G   Era designator (before christ, after christ)
y   Year (e.g. 12 or 2012). Use either yy or yyyy.
M   Month in year. Number of M's determine length of format (e.g. MM, MMM or MMMMM)
d   Day in month. Number of d's determine length of format (e.g. d or dd)
h   Hour of day, 1-12 (AM / PM) (normally hh)
H   Hour of day, 0-23 (normally HH)
m   Minute in hour, 0-59 (normally mm)
s   Second in minute, 0-59 (normally ss)
S   Millisecond in second, 0-999 (normally SSS)
E   Day in week (e.g Monday, Tuesday etc.)
D   Day in year (1-366)
F   Day of week in month (e.g. 1st Thursday of December)
w   Week in year (1-53)
W   Week in month (0-5)
a   AM / PM marker
k   Hour in day (1-24, unlike HH's 0-23)
K   Hour in day, AM / PM (0-11)
z   Time Zone
'   Escape for text delimiter
'   Single quote